# keypress issue in repainting canvas

Tags: java-me, canvas

Develping a Java Me application using Canvas,for first time canvas displaying 5 items in canvas,after some time canvas updates some more time to current canvas.If I press downup key when repainting the canvas,Its giving some blank space In between items in the screen.If I press after repainting Its works fine.
How can I lock for keypress when repainting Is ongoing.give one solution for this.